# PostSharp CompileTimeInitialize method not called during build

Tags: postsharp

We have recently upgraded from PostSharp 3.0.37 to 3.1.48. Since then our custom MethodInterceptionAspect no longer add the Initalize() method (via CompileTimeInitialize) on the build server. Bizarrely enough the dlls created by PostSharp in VisualStudio have the Initalization code as expected.

Based on the PostSharp release docs there have not been any installation changes between the two version.

We have license keys included in source control.

Has anyone come across this previously?

EDIT:

An example compile time initialize code:

```
public abstract class BaseMethodInterceptionAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    protected bool IsAsync { get; set; }

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        var methodInfo = method as MethodInfo;
        if (methodInfo == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("MethodInfo is null");
        }

        IsAsync = typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(methodInfo.ReturnType);

        base.CompileTimeInitialize(method, aspectInfo);
    }

    public sealed override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (!IsAsync)
        {
            // do one thing
        }
        else
        {
            // do another
        }
    }
}
```

When decompiling one of the assemblies(TypedLoggerShimFactory) which use aspects the build server dll is missing:

```
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGenerated]
    static TypedLoggerShimFactory()
    {
        <>z__a_18.Initialize();
    }
```

Edit 2:
PostSharp is running on the assembley in question:

[PostSharp30] 
C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\3.1.58\bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x86.exe obj\Release\Before-PostSharp\Iwi.Platform.WCFServiceManager.dll 
/X:default
/NoLogo
/P:Output=C:\BuildAgent\work\67a99d05742f768a\Iwi.Platform.WCFServiceManager\obj\Release\Iwi.Platform.WCFServiceManager.dll 
/P:ReferenceDirectory=C:\BuildAgent\work\67a99d05742f768a\Iwi.Platform.WCFServiceManager
/P:Configuration=Release 
/P:Platform=AnyCPU

"/P:SearchPath=..\bin\Release\|obj\Release\|C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\|C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\ " /P:IntermediateDirectory=obj\Release\PostSharp /P:CleanIntermediate=False /P:MSBuildProjectFullPath=C:\BuildAgent\work\67a99d05742f768a\Iwi.Platform.Library\Iwi.Platform.Library.csproj /P:SignAssembly=False /P:PrivateKeyLocation= /P:PrivateKeyContai...

Thank you,

Comment: The important difference between build-server and VisualStudio builds when you're using Express license is that the build-server still uses commercial-level license. This, for example, can cause certain optimizations to be invoked on the build-server, that are not invoked on developer's machine. Could you describe in more details what exactly is missing in the dlls created on the build-server? Or add a sample code of your CompileTimeInitialize method?

Comment: @AlexD thank you for your response, that makes sense. Code examples attached. Are there any guidelines how initialization code should be handled? thank you for your help.

Comment: Ok, we should also check whether PostSharp is executed at all on the build-server. Do any other aspects work correctly for build-server assemblies? If PostSharp runs, you should see the following message in the build log `: message : PostSharp 4.1 [4.1.13.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.379893, Release] complete...`.

Comment: Another thing to check - do you use NuGet package restore feature or do you commit packages to source control? If you use package restore, then please refer to http://doc.postsharp.net/nuget-restore for info on how to set it up correctly on the build-server.

Comment: Thanks again Alex. PostSharp is running (see edit2) above, further more when I disassemble the dll I can see other parts of the aspect correctly injected into my code. We have a build step which downloads nuget packages before building. This has not changed and works for all the nuget packages we download.

Comment: Actually, in the logs we see PostSharp starting (as above), but we do not see the "complete" message. However looking at the logs for 3.0.37 we do not see the complete

Comment: The Initialize() call in the static ctor is actually related to the RuntimeIntialize() method of the aspect. If you don't have the runtime initialization in your aspect then the method is optimized away. Is there any other symptom indicating that CompileTimeInitialize() method is not called during the build? (e.g. IsAsync property is not set correctly)

Comment: @AlexD that makes sense, we noticed that when we have the static constructor everything works, however when it is missing it doesnt - what I mean by that is the aspect itself is null, which I guess would point to some issues with deserialization when things are optimized on the build server? Were optimizations add after 3.0.37? That version doesnt seem to remove the static constructor (and I guess do other things which are causing us pain).

Comment: That may be a clue as well, there were some changes in serializer that could be incompatible between versions. But the problem should show up only if your build server reuses some of the binaries built with the older version of PostSharp (3.0.37).